# swiftUI core data model

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have created a swiftUI view and trying to display a core data entity but the preview fails and the app crashes during runtime. How to instantiate a `Movie` object and use it as a state member in swiftUI?

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var movie: Movie = Movie()

    var body: some View {
        Text(movie.title ?? "empty")
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        SwiftUIView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this, it will create a new instance in Core Data each time you load the view?

Comment: It's just a demo to preview the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create CoreData object with context, so here is possible way

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State private var movie: Movie?

    var body: some View {
        Text(movie.title ?? "empty")
           .onAppear {
              self.movie = Movie(context: viewContext)    // << here !!
           }
    }
}
```